# Solving the domain and range of a region satisfying two inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, inequality

The question I was provided was:

"Find the domain and range of the region satisfied by the following inequalities: 
i) $y \ge (x-1)^2$
ii)$y \le2x+1$

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Would you recommend graphing or solving algebraically?

Comment: hint: solved the equations,you will have some points and then check the max and min.

Comment: I seriously have no clue what to do. I tried expanding at all. Could you please provide a full explanation in the answers?r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am giving you a very basic way to find out the regions graphically. For $$y\ge(x-1)^2$$ Note that $y=(x-1)^2$ is a polynomial which has $\mathbb R$ as domain and obviously $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ as its range. To find out what that inequality tells you, you can pick two points in and out of the region the parabola made in $\mathbb R^2$. As you see $P$ is in and $Q$ is out with respect the parabola. Now satisfy the coordinates of $P$ into the inequality. You see $$(1/2-1)^2=1/4$$ and it is smaller than $2$. The same for $Q$ tells us $$(3-1)^2=4$$ is greater than $1$. So, the desired region satisfying $$y\ge(x-1)^2$$ is the parabola an the region which is enclosed by it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got that :D, but how would you solve the domain and range?

Comment: @missiledragon: The domain doesn't change but the range will be restricted. I cannot say that it is all $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$.

Comment: I'm lost. I've only tried analysing the graph but I got that both the domain and range are infinite. Can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: @missiledragon: Both are infinite. I don't think we can show the range in any understandable form but $\{y\mid y\ge (x-1)^2\}$.

Comment: @BabakS.:$\Large{+➊}{Ⓝ}{ⓘ}{ⓒ}{ⓔ}$ ⓦⓞⓡⓚ

Comment: Very nice work, indeed!  $\large{+}$ $\left[- \left(-\dfrac{119}{119}\right)\right]$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I explain more detail:

first ,let $y=2x+1,y=(x-1)^2$, you will have two points$(0,1)$ and $(4,9)$

$ y \le 2x+1$ means all points below the red line, for example, $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)$

$y \ge (x-1)^2$ means all points within the Parabola，for example $(1,1)(2,2)$

so two curves will have a closed area. the domain and range are: $ [0,4]$ and $[0,9]$